# Lisp Hash Table Equality Test

Tags: lisp, hashtable, common-lisp, sbcl

I made a hash table with `:test #'equalp`. My keys are structures of this type

```
#S(KEY
        :WMES (#S(WME
                  :TYPE BLOCK
                  :NAME B1
                  :ABS-POS ((^LEFT 0) (^RIGHT 20) (^BOTTOM 0) (^TOP 5))
                  :TIME-STAMP 0)
               #S(WME
                  :TYPE BLOCK
                  :NAME B2
                  :ABS-POS ((^LEFT 15) (^RIGHT 20) (^BOTTOM 5) (^TOP 10))
                  :TIME-STAMP 0)
               #S(WME
                  :TYPE GRIPPER
                  :NAME G1
                  :ABS-POS ((^X 10) (^Y 100))
                  :TIME-STAMP 0))
        :GOALS (DUMMY-GOAL)
        :ACTIONS (DUMMY-ACTION))
```

When I do `(equalp <key1> <key2>)` the function returns true if the two keys are structurally the same and have the same content.

On the contrary, when I check for a key in the hash table by using `(gethash <key> *my-hash*)`, the function returns `nil nil` even though there is a value associated with that key. Can anybody explain why `(equalp <key1> <key2>)` and `:test #'equalp` are returning different results?

My Lisp implementation is SBCL, and I'm using slime in emacs.

I appreciate the help.

**EDIT**

Here are the structure definitions

```
(defstruct key
  (wmes '() :type list)
  (goals '() :type list)
  (actions '() :type list))

(defstruct wme
  (type '() :type symbol)
  (name '() :type symbol)
  (abs-pos '() :type list)
  (time-stamp 0 :type integer))
```

Comment: Hard to say without a reproducible test case.

Comment: Really just a guess: maybe you are interning those symbols `^left` etc. in the wrong package when `read`ing them from some serialized form?  You could try `trace`ing `equalp`.

Comment: Expanding on @Svante's comment: are you interning the symbols at all? If you are using `make-symbol`, you are out of luck: `(equalp (make-symbol "a") (make-symbol "a"))` ==> `NIL`. Set `*print-readably*` to `t` before printing your keys.

Comment: No, I'm not using make-symbol thankfully. I'm trying to make a test case that reproduces my bug, so hang tight guys

Comment: Does `sxhash` give the same result for both keys?

Comment: I am experiencing similar behavior. In my case, I am doing some logical checks on the values such as `consp` and other. Whenever I create a table without specifying `:test`, the table does not seem to recognize that that key exists. However, once I recreate the table with `:test 'equal `, it works. Were you able to get to the cause of this?